# A case reducer on a non-draftable value must not return undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm working on my project `@reduxjs/toolkit` and created `UserSlice` like below.

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { User } from "../../models";

export type UserState = User | null;

export const initialUserState: UserState = null;

const UserSlice = createSlice({
  name: "User",
  initialState: initialUserState,
  reducers: {
    receiveUser: (state: UserState, action: PayloadAction<UserState>) => {
      state = action.payload;
    },
    clearUser: (state: UserState, _action: PayloadAction<void>) => {
      state = null;
    },
    signIn: (
      _,
      _action: PayloadAction<{
        email: string;
        password: string;
      }>
    ) => {},
    signInWithToken: (_, _action: PayloadAction<void>) => {},
  },
});

export default UserSlice;
```

`signIn` `signInWithToken` are action creators just for taking actions in `UserSaga` module, so they do nothing.

When I dispatch `signIn` action, below error occurs.

```
index.js:1 Error: A case reducer on a non-draftable value must not return undefined
    at createReducer.ts:163
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at createReducer.ts:143
...
```

This code snippets pattern works fine my other projects, but this project. I can't figure out the reason of this error, so I'm asking this question. Are there any faults in my code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you're not returning the state in all of your reducers, because when using arrow functions objects need additional round brackets:

```
  reducers: {
    receiveUser: (state: UserState, action: PayloadAction<UserState>) => ({
      state: action.payload;
    }),
    clearUser: (state: UserState, _action: PayloadAction<void>) => ({
      state : null;
    }),
    signIn: (
      _,
      _action: PayloadAction<{
        email: string;
        password: string;
      }>
    ) => ({}),
    signInWithToken: (_, _action: PayloadAction<void>) => ({}),
  },
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Interesting, however, not returning state was not an issue before.

Answer (score 17):

Redux Toolkit's `createReducer()` allows writing reducers that [directly mutate the state](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation). This works by wrapping the reducer call with `produce` from the [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) library.

However, the reducer call [isn't wrapped with `produce`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/23a0e43149503198bc56014a63b8572162631519/src/createReducer.ts#L157-L168) when the current state isn't "draftable" by Immer, which is the case for primitive values, including `null`:

```
} else if (!isDraftable(previousState)) {
  // If state is not draftable (ex: a primitive, such as 0), we want to directly
  // return the caseReducer func and not wrap it with produce.
  const result = caseReducer(previousState as any, action)

  if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
    throw Error(
      'A case reducer on a non-draftable value must not return undefined'
    )
  }

  return result
}
```

Because your initial User state is `null`, you must return the new state from your `receiveUser()` reducer.

Comment: Man this was exactly my issue! Thank you so much for your answer, this fixed it immediately.

Comment: Awesome explanation! I wasn't sure if this applied to me since I was starting with a boolean state, but then saw you said 'primitives'. problem solved :)

Comment: Holy f, this was top tier explaination and it solved my problem as well. I used `createSlice({ initialState: "lol" })` but "lol" is a primitive string so I had to change it to `createSlice({ initialState: { value: "lol" } })`.

Answer (score 2):

The arrow function has two syntax forms:

- (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
- (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression

The first one does not necessarily return a value unless it contains a `return` statement, but the second will return a value. You are using the first form without a return inside, so it won't return anything.

Since the rule is that `a case reducer on a non-draftable value must not return undefined`, and you can parenthesize the body of a function to return an object literal expression like this:

```js
params => ({foo: bar})
```

You can rewrite your code to this:

```js
reducers: {
  receiveUser: (state: UserState, action: PayloadAction<UserState>) => ({
    state: action.payload;
  }),
  clearUser: (state: UserState, _action: PayloadAction<void>) => ({
    state : null;
  }),
  signIn: (
    _,
    _action: PayloadAction<{
      email: string;
      password: string;
    }>
  ) => ({}),
  signInWithToken: (_, _action: PayloadAction<void>) => ({}),
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error then I tried using initialState:{value:0} instead of initialState:0 I made initialState Value to An Object & it is working

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues:

1. You probably just need to bump your version of `@reduxjs/toolkit` to the latest version by `npm i @reduxjs/toolkit@latest` or `yarn add @reduxjs/toolkit@latest`.

There was a version that had a bug where if you initialized state with null, this could potentially happen. If you install the latest and there is still an issue, please let me know which version you're on and I'll try to reproduce it.

2. The other possible issue is that if your `action.payload` in `receiveUser` is actually undefined, you'll get that error as you shouldn't ever be returning undefined.